# Resultset from MySql using Java/Spring is empty, and it should not have been

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I am building code to access a database using Spring and Java from my standard dataobjects. My local setup uses a MySQL-installation, for simplicity. I have been able to perform inserts fine using my code, but I cannot get data out of select-operations...

I have a table in MySql. The database is called jonathan, the table is called Project, and it has an id column in it.

There was originally one row, but I have now inserted three rows in the table, which have been inserted using my java/spring-code.

I have singled out my problem and condensed the testing of the particular problem here, I have removed any where-clause to make sure there is no parameter-mapping problem involved. I have debugged the code to make sure I do receive a datasource.

```
public class TestDb extends MappingSqlQuery {
    public TestDb() {
        super(StorageFactory.getDataSource(), "Select id from jonathan.Project");
    }
    @Override
    protected Object mapRow(ResultSet arg0, int arg1) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println(arg1+" rows");
        for(int i=0;i<arg1;i++) {
            System.out.println(i+": "+arg0.getString(i));
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I test this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestDb t = new TestDb();
    t.execute();
    System.out.println("Test done");
}
```

I get

```
0 rows
Test done
```

I have tried different casings on the table name also.

---

Solution:
I confirmed that I could select the data using only jdbc, so the problem was how I accessed the results.

I found that the following worked:

```
public class TestDb extends MappingSqlQuery {
    public TestDb() {
        super(StorageFactory.getDataSource(), "Select id from jonathan.project");
    }
    @Override
    protected Object mapRow(ResultSet arg0, int arg1) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println(arg1 + " rows?");
        boolean b=arg0.first();
        while (b) {
            System.out.println(arg0.getInt(1));
            b=arg0.next();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The print says
0 rows?

```
100000
100001
100002
Test done
```

I still wonder what arg1 is supposed to give me, because as far as I can tell it always says 0. I expected it to hold the number of rows selected.
Also, the documentation for ResultSet says

> A ResultSet cursor is initially
>   positioned before the first row; the
>   first call to the method next makes
>   the first row the current row; the
>   second call makes the second row the
>   current row, and so on.

giving me the idea I could just next() through the whole ResultSet, but if I do first() and then next() it appears to work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** :

Can you try at the beginning of mapRow :

```
if (!this.isCompiled()) System.out.println("Compilation needed !");
```

Then please try also at the beginning of mapRow :

```
if (!arg0.first()) System.out.println("Empty RS !");
else System.out.println("RS contains lines!");
```

If you've got "RS contains lines" text, then do `i<=arg1` instead of `i<arg1` in your loop.
Elsewhere, I'll try to find something else to help you :)

Comment: Read the question: *I am certain I have contact with the right database, because if I edit the table name in the query to say Projec I get an [Exception]*.

Comment: @BalusC Ok ok ... Was 2:30 in the night, I misread, sorry. I'll have a real look once awaken :)

Comment: @BalusC Edited my first post, trying to find a solution, thanks for letting me know I've been misreading :)

Comment: Just tried this. Curious matter... I do not get the "Compilation needed", but I do get "RS contains lines". So somehow, it knows there is data, it just doesn't want to give to me :-) i<=arg1 gives me an java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, 0 < 1.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I'll edit my post in a bit. I've been accessing the result wrong. I need to test it with multiple rows before I'm completely certain how to do it right, but if I just do a System.out.println(arg0.getInt("id")); without entering any loop I get correct data

Comment: @MortenT Great if that helped :) 
What I would do is a first(), access the line, get the id, then do a while (arg0.next()) loop.

Comment: That's what I ended up on as well. Edited my post above to reflect also the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

MappingSqlQuery is meant to be used for converting each row to one object and return a list containing all objects in a list.
So mapRow is called once for each row in the ResultSet. But when you manually iterate the cursor you end the ResultSet on the first call to mapRow, that's why arg1 isn't incremented.
Normally you would have had spring call your implementation of mapRow 3 times and arg1 would be 0 to 2.

I know this answer is way too late and you've probably solved this years ago but I hope it might help someone else with the same problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

Doing `first()` and then `next()` is wrong, you only need `next()`.

`first()` might even fail if you have a `FORWARD_ONLY` ResultSet.

The correct way to loop through a result set is:

```
while (arg0.next())
{ 
    // call arg0.getXXX() here
}
```

But with Spring you don't need that. mapRow() will be called for each row in the ResultSet and Spring will do the looping (based on `next()`) for you.

> *I still wonder what arg1 is supposed to give me*

Well, it helps to [read the JavaDocs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/object/MappingSqlQuery.html#mapRow%28java.sql.ResultSet,%20int%29):

> *Parameters:
>
>     rs - ResultSet we're working through
>
>     rowNum - row number (from 0) we're up to*

So your method should look like this:

```
@Override
protected Object mapRow(ResultSet arg0, int arg1) throws SQLException {
    System.out.println("At row #" + arg1);
    System.out.println(i+": "+arg0.getString(1)); // get column 1 from the result set
    return null;
}
```

As your SELECT only returns a single column, there is no need for a loop (over the columns) inside the `mapRow()` method